# How do you use the ballistic knife in black ops 4?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-4

I never understood how to aim with it and need a bit of help

Answer (score 1):

The Ballistic Knife is projectile-based, meaning you have to account for the knife's drop - it doesn't travel in a straight path like a bullet does in this game.  In addition to this, just like with a regular weapon, if the target is moving you need to account for this.  However, you need to consider that the knife is considerably slower than a bullet, thus it might require you to aim where you *think* your target is going to be when the knife reaches the target.

Aside from this, you really need to practice using it to get a feel for it.  As I said, the two biggest things is accounting for the drop, and predicting where your target will be when the knife reaches it.